# Color Overlay added to Adjustment Layer does not show

Tags: color, adobe-after-effects, fill, layer-style

I put an adjustment layer on top of my video. I right clicked and went to layer styles and clicked color overlay. It did nothing but add color overlay to the list of properties under the Adjustment layer. Despite having an opacity of 100% and the color red, it does not show up in the video. It's like it isn't there. How do I make it show up? I don't want to use a fill layer because I can't animate the color there, that color would stay the same.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do that... There's nothing for the color to overlay. Why can you animate the color on an adjustment layer but not on a solid layer?

Comment: Because the solid layer is set to a specific color on creation, It's stuck to the layer itself.

Comment: Not if you use a color overlay...

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the answer is to use Color Overlay but add it to a solid layer not an adjustment layer.